# Building a JSON from a database query of country, state, city and each cities latitude/longitude

Tags: javascript, json

I have a table that has country, state, city, latitude/longitude of the city. I am trying to build a json string as show below.

```
{
  "country": "usa",
  "states": [
    {
      "name": "Alabama",
      "state_code": "AL",
      "cities": [
        {
          "name": "Abbeville",
          "latitude": "31.57184000",
          "longitude": "-85.25049000"
        },
        {
          "name": "Adamsville",
          "latitude": "33.60094000",
          "longitude": "-86.95611000"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Alaska",
      "state_code": "AK",
      "cities": [
        {
          "name": "Akutan",
          "latitude": "54.13350000",
          "longitude": "-165.77686000"
        },
        {
          "name": "Aleutians East Borough",
          "latitude": "54.85000000",
          "longitude": "-163.41667000"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The database query results are in a array: jsonData. I have the code that put's the country. Not sure how to add a state if it doesn't exist and a city if it doesn't exist with the cities latitude and longitude  (the portion where I have ???)

```
let jsonData1 = [];
for (let item of jsonData) {
  if(countryExists(jsonData1, item['COUNTRY'])) {
    ??
  }
  else {
    jsonData1.push({ country: item['COUNTRY']});
  }
}


function countryExists (JSON, country) {
  var hasMatch = false;

  for (var index = 0; index < JSON.length; ++index) {
      var item  = JSON[index];
      if(item.country === country) {
        hasMatch = true;
        break;
      }
  }
  return hasMatch;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to stick with the schema you choose, you could when you adding a country with no states, set the value of the state's name to a default e.g. `none`, you could also do the same for the `latitude` and `longitude`.

However, I would recommend reconsidering the schema of your data.

Comment: I want it in a format that is easier to read process using a loop in another application. That's why I chose that schema. What schema are you suggesting?

Comment: @RaviM The thing is with your schema is that you are having the `cities`  inside the `states` while most of the countries in the world don't have states...

Comment: Thanks. As you suggested, I could add a state called none if there are countries without a state. I still need help with figuring out how to check if a state exists within a country before adding and if a city exists within a country/state before adding it. I have tried a few combinations and can't seem to get it to work.